# Dismiss 2 ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, popover

I'm making an app whereas a popover ViewController modals to a new ViewController on a button press. When the user is done in the new VC, he/she presses ok and that should be dismissed alongside with the popover ViewController. I tried to use a notification to trigger the popover VC to close, but I can't as the other is being dismissed at the same time.

I see that the dismissing code has a completion token:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I set the completion:popoverVC and make that handle it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}];
```

Comment: Doesn't dismiss the popover, only the other VC @Antzi

Comment: I changed the navigation type from popover to modal and push and that fixed it together with your code :)